# Find negation of particular keywords in text

Tags: python, nlp, regex-negation, data-extraction

I am working on information extraction from medical texts (very new to NLP!). At the moment I am interested to find and extract the medications which are mentioned in a predefined list of drugs. For example, consider the text:

> "John was prescribed aspirin due to hight temperature"

Thus, given the list of medications (in Python language):

```
list_of_meds = ['aspirin', 'ibuprofen', 'paracetamol']
```

The extracted drug is `aspirin`. That's fine.

Now consider another case:

> "John was prescribed ibuprofen, because he could not tolerate paracetamol"

Now, if I extract the drugs using the list (for example with regular expression), then the extracted drugs are `ibuprofen` and `paracetamol`.

**QUESTION** How to separate actually prescribed and untolerated drugs? Is there a way to label prescribed (used) and other mentioned drugs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complex problem. To capture the nuances around negation, you need to step into the world of **dependency parsing** and **relationship extraction**. Couple of paths you can take to add sophistication to your current approach and the add-on by @Jordan are:

1. Using a relationship extraction NLP library (e.g. Watson, Core-NLP, Spacy) that you train with example sentences like the one you gave to extract triplet relations like (John, prescribed, ibuprofen) and (John, not tolerate, paracetamol). This will require investment in annotating sample data.
2. Rolling your own relationship extractor by starting with the dependency parse that shows how different parts of the sentence are related. This will require both programming time as well as training.

Handling negation in relations is not a solved problem. The state of the art around this is usually associated with sentiment analysis. An introduction on using dependency parsing to identify and handle negation is available at this [Stanford NLP Sentiment Analysis using RNN page](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sentiment/rntnDemo.html)

Answer (score 2):

A way to overcome this would be predefining what word comes before the medicine name. So in your case, this would mean checking to see if either "prescribed" or "not tolerate" comes before the medicine name.

This is what I have come up with. Just replace the variable `text = first` with `text = second` if you want to try the second piece of text.

```
import string

list_of_meds = ['aspirin', 'ibuprofen', 'paracetamol']
first = "John was prescribed aspirin due to high temperature"
second = "John was prescribed ibuprofen, because he could not tolerate 
paracetamol"

text = first

for c in string.punctuation:                                                                                                     
    text = text.replace(c, "")
text = text.split(' ')
for i in text:
    if i in list_of_meds:
        index = text.index(i) - 1
        if text[index] == "prescribed":
            medicine = i
            break
```

Good luck!

Jordan.

----- EDIT -----

Use the variable `medicine` as the output, and you can use that variable from there.

Comment: NIce point, thanks! However, the problem is that the word 'prescribed' or 'not tolerated' could be written in many different ways. These are really medical notes and doctors may write/mention tolerance or prescription in many ways, so building another list of precursor words could be a real challenge. I am wondering, whether there are ways to learn from the text the meaning of prescribed and all other mentions of the drugs.

Comment: Another way that you could do it would be to create a list of synonyms, and replace `"prescribed"` with the list. A way to get around the formatting of the sentences would be to either provide templates in the code, which will be very much hardcoding, or you could count the how far the word is from the name of the medicine. But if it really becomes a problem, you might want to consider to create a default medical note format for the doctors to follow.